# How to fix this error: "Execution failed: illegal argument" in getRange("A3") from an active sheet?

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've build this script to add a new row in the index 3 of the sheet if the range (3, 5) (or "A3") is empty. Doing so, I don't need to scroll until to last empty row to add values to the sheet, I just add them in this third empty row, which is created when I open the document. But there is a problem: the function is working only when I open one of the sheets of the spreadsheet document (to be precise, the one of `#gid=7`), despite the fact that there is no such condition in my function. So, if I open my spreadhseet doc without any `#gid=GID_NUMBER`) or if I open it through a url with `#gid=7`, it shows `First Menu`. But if, I don't do this (eg, if I open it from others `#gid=`), the `First Menu` is not shown. When the log shows this error message: **`Execution failed: illegal argument. (line 2252, file "mainScript") [0:06 seconds of total runtime]`**. Line 2252 is this:

```
Logger.log("activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue() = "+activeSheet.getRange("A3").getValue() );
```

The same error is shown when this line is replaced for this other:

```
if(activeSheet.getRange("A3").getValue() !== '') {
```

If I replace the `"A3"` argument with `getRange(3, 1)` I get the same error. The curious thing is that this error doesn't happen when I open the sheet with `#gid=7`. **The error occurs after the execution of `range.getValue`**. How to fix that? Here is a sample of the code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onOpen() {
  insertEmptyRow();
  var menuEntries = 
    [
    {name: "My Menu", functionName: "myFunction"}
    ];
  ss.addMenu("First menu", menuEntries);
 }

function insertEmptyRow(){
   if(activeSheet.getRange("A3").getValue() !== '') {
     activeSheet.insertRows(3);
     Logger.log("activeSheet.getRange("A3").getValue() = " + activeSheet.getRange("A3").getValue() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually editing the URL with a custom gid, may I ask?

Comment: The document has several gids and I have to edit them. Each gid has a unique `#gid=NUMBER`.

Comment: Remove the first two globals, they will cause trouble. Put them inside a function.

Comment: Have you tried an installable onOpen ? I do it quite often when the "normal" onOpen doesn't fire ;)

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, I dind't tryied it yet. Since the documentation says "The onInstall() trigger is called when an add-on is installed from the add-on store or a script is installed from the (only in the older version of Google Sheets).", should I use an installable `onOpen` with the new version of GAS? Could you provide some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @ZigMandel, I think the error is related with the your observation. But I replace the global variables with local ones and the error persists. Any help?

Comment: look at @Sergeinsas answer where he does what i suggest and solves the authorization issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An installable onOpen will probably be the best solution since your `onOpen` function needs authorization to run (access spreadsheet Service).

Just change the function name to avoid double firing.

sample code from your example :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function installableOnOpen() {
  insertEmptyRow();
  var menuEntries = 
    [
    {name: "My Menu", functionName: "myFunction"}
    ];
  ss.addMenu("First menu", menuEntries);
 }

function insertEmptyRow(){
   if(activeSheet.getRange(3, 5).getValue() !== '') {
     activeSheet.insertRows(3);
     Logger.log("activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValues() = " + activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue() );
  }
}
```

[test spreadsheet with view rights, make a copy to use and/or modify.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164qJ8xjwuSrh6Qn7WFGVvdKQgrQA2XwCDugq0pwjv7U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, I change the original question to add the error message log (Sorry for haven't done that before!). Could you provide some help?

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, I just tried your test spreadsheet (making a copy and with the authorization). But the error persist. Any idea? Here my test ss copy: http://goo.gl/8Q0cRj

Comment: (anyway I choose your answer because it's the most complete and had a great effort)

Comment: I tried your test and it works nicely... what issue do you have ? still the menu not showing up unless you specify a special gid ? Apart from creating the trigger and authorize I didn't change anything to your sheet.(btw, thx for accepting, too bad it's after the bounty period;-))

Comment: I had to use https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10fHlkJWkujVfHSkg2xRXlEXN7qqSG0kP1-CIdPmI768/edit#gid=1533833194  to open on Sheet2 and it worked also.

Answer (score 1):

I think below is what you require. Please tell me if this is incorrect, as I have found some disparity in your original post compared with your code sample.

Given you have said `add a new row in the index 3 of the sheet if the first cell in the row 3 is empty`, I will go off this.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    insertEmptyRow(activeSheet);
    var menuEntries = [{name: "My Menu", functionName: "myFunction"}];
    ss.addMenu("First menu", menuEntries);
}

function insertEmptyRow(){
    //if(activeSheet.getRange(3, 5).getValue() !== "") { <-- I don't know why you are checking the 5th cell here, as you clearly state first cell in third row as above.

    if(activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue() !== ''){
        activeSheet.insertRows(3);
        Logger.log("activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue() = " + activeSheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue()); <-- I'm also not sure about this, as you check the value of row 3, cell 1 AFTER you have inserted a row. This will always be empty, but you might be doing this for error checking to ensure the process completed properly, so I left it.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you are having trouble with it not working. The logic behind the code was wrong anyway which I fixed for you. Not sure about your GID problem. Try this and let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, @CameronC . But I really did a mistake in my explanation. It's not the first cell of row 3, but the range (3,5) and this part of function is ok (like yours). My problem is exactly with the `#gid=` problem. It only works in one gid! (the number 7). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey I just realised I made an error in my answer. It should be 

`function insertEmptyRow(activeSheet){`


Sorry I couldn't fix it for you. I thought it would work for all occurrences as long as the onOpen script is associated to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, @CameronC, I change the original question to add the error message log (Sorry for haven't done that before!). Could you provide me some help?